# Optimize Reading large Raster with gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I'm a newbie with python/Gdal. I try to calculate distance from a point to each cell of a large raster (10000x10000).
 
I manage to do it with the folllowing code using python/gdal but it is very slow (about 18min). 
I've also try top do it using numpy array but I've got Memory error..
I'd really appreciate help to optimize this if it's possible.

here's my code :

```
raster = gdal.Open('/raster.tif')

rows = raster.RasterXSize
cols = raster.RasterYSize
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)

geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
xUpperleft = geotransform[0]
yUpperLeft = geotransform[3]
pixelSizex = geotransform[1]
pixelSizey = geotransform[5]

data = band.ReadAsArray(0,0,rows,cols)

for x in range(0, rows):
    for y in range(0, cols):
        #xp,yp centroid coordinates for each cell
        #Xreference,YReference are the coordiantes to calculate the distance to each cell grid. 
        xp = y * pixelSizex + xUpperleft + (pixelSizex / 2) #add half the cell size
        yp = x * pixelSizey + yUpperLeft + (pixelSizey / 2) #to centre the point
        distance = math.sqrt((xp-xReference)**2 + (yp-yReference)**2)

        data[x,y]=distance
```

Thanks a lot.
 
Pasch.

Comment: What is the slowest part?  Reading the raster or iterating over the for loop?  Since you are not modifying any shared data inside the loop, that is a good candidate for multithreading.  Otherwise, the given file size may limit your options as the File IO is probably not optimized for Python as you are doing a C++ to Python conversion through SWIG.

Comment: Hi, the slowest part is the iteration over the for loop. Do you have some example of multithreading ? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your code you read data as array, and then in the end of for loop set it in place to the distance value.

```
    data = band.ReadAsArray(0,0,rows,cols)
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
            ...
             data[x,y]=distance
```

I don't know what you do with this data after but how about try to put this distance value in a dictionary for further processing even looping over it to save a new raster, rather than changing the numpy array inplace.

like:

```
    data = {{}}
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
         ...
            data[x][y]=distance
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading an entire raster at once is efficient but not a choice for large rasters since you will get out of memory errors. Reading a raster pixel by pixel is easy but this time you will get terrible performance.

The solution is in between.

Reading large rasters efficiently certainly requires reading with *pixel blocks*. I have recently read and processed a GeoTiff having 1.6 GB size and 30K x 30K pixels with GDAL. Reading time was 2.6 seconds. Here the size of the pixel blocks comes into play. Testing  with different block sizes showed that 256x256 gave the best results for me. You may want to try and find the optimized size for your case, though.

The method to read as blocks is (Java signature)

```
public int ReadRaster​(int xoff, int yoff, int xsize, int ysize, short[] array)
```

Here is a link that I found useful when reading rasters. Please look at the section with title "Reading raster data efficiently". The code is with Python but it is easy to adapt to other languages. (I have adapted it with Java GDAL bindings with no problems.)

[https://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf](https://www.gis.usu.edu/%7Echrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf)