# GDAL ReadRaster data array access orientation

Tags: c#, gdal

I am using OSGeo.GDAL C# API version 3.6.3 to read elevation raster via the following code:

```
int xOff = 464917;
int yOff = 158902;
int width = 10;
int height = 10;
double[] buffer = new double[100];
Band bnd = Obj.GetRasterBand(1);
bnd.ReadRaster(xOff, yOff, width, height, buffer, width, height, 0, 0);
```

my question is to confirm the grid read in is as below, right?

[image]

Comment: See following : https://gdal.org/tutorials/gdal_grid_tut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You compute pixel offsets **from the upper left corner** for specific coordinates. Here is a [GDAL C# Binding `ReadRaster()` Example](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/csharp/apps/GDALRead.cs).

For efficient reading of big raster files, you may find
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70470081/2638227) useful. It mentions how to *read a raster as blocks*.

Comment: an addon question: ReadRaster() reads column-wise, right? I mean it reads the first column and puts in the first n-elements in the result buffer array, then it reads the next column and puts in the next n-elements in the result buffer array, and so on, is that right?

Comment: No, `ReadRaster()` reads row-wise. In other words, it first reads the first row from left to right, then continues with the second row etc.

Comment: To make sure, I open the raster that I work with [Quantum GIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) and use its *Identification/Info* tool. If you click a cell then this tool displays the cell value in a panel. I find it useful this method for testing purposes.